# return caller caller page after login in struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-config

I have a download.jsp page which has an functionality of downloading the files only when he logins.
when ever he clicks the download option it asks for the login to download and he redirected to login page , when he authenticate the user should redirect to the download.jsp

here is my `struts.xml` file

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="loginAction" method="login" class="com.vaannila.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="sucess" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            <result name="failure" type="tiles">home</result>

        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

in LoginAction class i have only one method login which authenticates and returns either success or failure and resultant pages are called

how can i return the caller page download.jsp after login

Comment: would you mind post your "login" method of your controller? if you always want to return "download.jsp" it's very easy with action redirect. but if you want to return "previous page" you have to save that url somewhere, like a GET param or in session

Comment: the login method has can return only two values either "success or failure " as per user concern i kept a url in session . is it still possible to return to previous page with returning the "sucess or faiure"

Answer (score 0):

You have few options which you can try to achieve the said functionality

`HTTP Referer` header like

```
final String refer = request.getHeader("Referer");
```

There is few issues with this, firewall and well browser can block it, which might cause some issues, though i have not seen any such issue and have used it few times.

Other solution which is more reliable is to use a hidden files or append current page URL as a query string and use it in your application like

```
<a href="login?destination=theCurrentUrl">Login</a>
```

you can use this variable to find out the current page URL and can redirect it after login.

If you are using Spring security, it has this feature build in where it stores the information from where use came and will redirect back to same page after authentication.

Hope this might help you